# SQL Server 2012 takes long time on simple alter to add NULL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, alter-table

I have a problem to alter table in SQL Server 2012, it takes a long time to add 04 columns being allowed `NULL` to large table with 340 columns and approximately 166M rows and 01 non-clustered index

This problem happens only specific table after restoring. 
I'm waiting the execution for 10 hours but it's not finished so I must cancel it for more investigation. It's such strange because the script is really really simple as below, and we have done it successfully before:

```
alter table sample_database.sample_schema.sample_table
add column_001 int null
   ,column_002 numeric(18,4) null
   ,column_003 nvarchar(500) null
   ,column_004 int null;
```

My questions are:

- Why does it happen strangely?
- How to solve this because it's related to our deployment package? We have done the workaround as creating new table with new columns and load data. But it doesn't work to us.
- How to prevent this problem in the future?

Many thanks all,

Comment: check this http://serverfault.com/questions/36696/how-to-speed-up-adding-column-to-large-table-in-sql-server

Comment: In my case, added columns are allowed NULL so they are not required to update row-by-row on new columns with default value. One more thing in your mentioned thread, I concern about dropping current index, then adding new columns and finally re-create index, is it good solution? Because as my understanding, re-create index would take time.

Comment: yes, it can help. also, be sure, table is unused in this time

Comment: Do you use sql 2012, right?

Comment: Try putting your code into transaction

Comment: @Anton: Yes, we use sql 2012

Comment: How long did it take to cancel?

Comment: `340 columns` is *way* too much. Remember that for future design, to keep the number of columns low. Normalize your data to reduce this number. If you do that at least you will not run into such problems in the future.

Comment: @MartinSmith It's still not completed.

Comment: @TT Yup but for this case, can not do that.

Comment: Do you have columnstore index on that table? if not any DDL triggers available? What is the FillFactor? Did you tried running profiler in background to see what is happening?

Comment: Is this happening in all environments? Did you tried adding Int nullable column? whether that is also taking time?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Not all environment, just UAT env. only, i'm still monitoring this case and when it rollback successfully, then i will try add just only 01 int nullable column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case happened in our UAT environment. After we restore the database again from the latest backup, this problem doesn't happen again. The alter is completed within mili-seconds.

In my opinion, there're certain issue since the last restoration.

Many thanks all,

Answer (score 4):

If it is 2012 (according to tag), this may happen:

http://rusanu.com/2012/02/16/adding-a-nullable-column-can-update-the-entire-table/

> If adding a nullable column in SQL Server 2012 has the potential of
>   increasing the row size over the 8060 size then the ALTER performs an
>   offline size-of-data update to every row of the table to ensure it
>   fits in the page. This behavior is new in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: . . Even updating every row doesn't explain why the query would take 10 hours . . . or more.

Comment: That update operation may involve massive page splits and pointers forwarding. With 166M rows and 340 columns, and not known configuration (vm / cloud, trans log increment, io, other db and non-db activities, etc.), it may happen

Comment: "This behavior is new in SQL Server 2012." This relates to SQL Server 2012. And how do we overcome and prevent this case?

Comment: @Anton For the example in the article, it relates to fix length char, but in my case, we use nvarchar as well.

Comment: You're adding fixed length columns with int and numeric datatypes, it's enough to trigger mentioned above behaviour. Caclulate the row size for all the rows to confirm it... You have too many columns, usually this is due to bad design. Consider creating more tables with one-to-one relationship, move some data to those new tables, and change all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is explained by @Anton. 
-Page Split

And for workaround you could follow these steps:

1. Create clone table with empty rows(e.g. `SELECT * INTO <New table> from sample_table WHERE 0=1`)
2. Add new columns in .
3. Copy data from sample_table to .
4. Once step 3 completes modify the sample_table name and rename  to sample_table.

You should also try to add columns with `NOT NULL` values and once columns added then modify it accordingly.

Comment: you can use 'bulk insert' to copy data between tables fast.

Comment: We still need to create PK and Idx, they will takes a lot of time too. I don't think alter with adding NOT NULL values saving the time, it should be more heavier

Comment: @JohnLe, Obviously index creation or rebuild would take time to execute as you have 166M records. But by copying data and renaming tables will reduce the load on current table.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and a simple server restart worked.